# Global RSS feed from Google Reader

Tags: google-reader, rss

Can I get a single feed combining all of my subscriptions out of Google Reader?

I mean I'm subscribed to 80 something feeds in Reader, and I want to use that as a single feed in another app.

Is that possible? If so how?

Answer (score 7):

If you tag every feed with a single tag (each feed can by in multiple tags/folders), you can make this tag public in the settings "Folders and Tags" tab and then use the feed provided by Google reader.

Answer (score 4):

Create a bundle.

Within Google Reader go to http://www.google.com/reader/view/#bundle-creator-page ("Browse for stuff" --> "Create a bundle").

Then drag all your feeds into the bundle and untick the checkbox "Add to my shared items".
Now when you save the bundle you will see it under "Your bundles" with 4 links next to it. One of those links is called "Add a link to your website or blog". When you click at that link you can see (and subscribe to) the atom feed of your newly created bundle.

Don't forget that at this point everyone in the world might be able to find out about all stuff you read.

Comment: Yes, I realize that making my reading list public will indeed make it available to anyone... That's why I'm not too keen about these methods.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you could look at using Yahoo Pipes - it can combine multiple feeds into a single one.

Comment: That is alot of modules. I am not sure if there is a limit on the number of modules you can have at a time.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough points on this site yet to comment, but I was also going to suggest the same thing that Grant did.

It depends on exactly what you're trying to do, but using the [OPML Aggregator Pipe](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=wGp8K2ze2xGAIubVX0sBXw) you can just point it at your Google Reader OPML.

Comment: That looks promising, but it doesn't seem to work properly... Also, I can't tell it use my google reader OPML directly, I have to download it then upload it somewhere else, and so if I add or remove feeds from google reader, I have to remember to update the OPML file

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use apps like [FeedDemon](http://www.feeddemon.com/), you don't need to combine all the feeds. It will automatically import all your subscribed feeds from Google Reader.